# Passing value from javascript to servlet through url

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am using submit button to get unique "ID" for the row using Javascript which should later pass this id value to servlet called EditRecord. When I enclose the submit button within forms the button value (unique id for the row) is not getting transported to the servlet and value is absent in the URL but when I plcae the submit button outside the form the I can see the button value but the page is redicrected to a blank page. DOnt know where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

here is the code for javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function editRecord(id)
    {
        url="EditRecord";
        window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/DbCon/"+url+"?id="+id;
        user_id="?id="+id;

    }
    </script>
```

The code for fetching records from table is given below:

```
<TABLE align="Center" border="1px" width="80%">
    <%Iterator itr;%>
    <%List data=(List) request.getAttribute("UserData");
    for(itr=data.iterator();itr.hasNext();)
    {%>
        <tr>
            <% String s= (String) itr.next(); %>
            <td><%=s %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>

            <form action="EditRecord" method="post">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"  onclick="editRecord(<%=s %>);"> </td>
            </form>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" onclick="deleteRecord(<%=s %>);"></td>

    <%} %>
    </tr>
```

My servlet code is given as below

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet res = null;
    String id = null  ;
    String query;
    DatabaseConnection dbconn;


//  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{

        id=request.getParameter(id);
        System.out.println(id);
        dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
        conn=dbconn.setConnection();
        System.out.println(conn);
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(stmt);
        query="select * from user_details where User_id="+id;
        res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
        System.out.println(res);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }finally{
        request.setAttribute("EditData", res);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/editdata.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Ajax?

Comment: @Dumisani I didnt use ajax as I dont know

Comment: @Dumisani — Why? That would only make things more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a string containing the name of the parameter to `getParameter`, you are passing the `id` variable which is defined as `String id = null`.

You want `"id"`, not `id`.

---

*Asides*

You have a try/catch block, but you don't do anything with the catch. If you looked at the exceptions you were generating you would find it much easier to debug your code!

You are inserting user input directly into some SQL. This renders you vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) and you need to [protect](http://bobby-tables.com/java.html) yourself from them.

Comment: @ Qunetin  Thanks for your reply. I tried but the id value for the clicked row is absent in URL when I clicked submit button. I dont where the problem is. Please guide me

Comment: @Thileepan — When you asked the original question you said the id *was* visible in the URL. That code I suggested you change runs after the code which generates the URL so it can't have caused that. You must have changed something else, change it back.

Comment: @ Quentin I have edited my question. Also the suggestion what you said was useful and I changed to "id" but I have stated my problem in my edited question.  Please guide me.